# convert string to float in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert string to float but I couldnt succeed.

here is my code

```
float f1 = Float.parseFloat("1,9698");
```

the error it gives is

```
Invalid float  "1,9698";
```

why is it doing this? it is a valid float

Comment: remove the ',' !!I think you wanted to add '.'

Comment: should I replace it with "." ?

Comment: @ayilmaz Yes, that is correct

Comment: @ayilmaz yes .replace it .I haved added the solution as answer also .

Comment: Your locale is not set correctly to allow commas in floating point numbers.  You need to use a locale which allows this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use something like this:

```
String text = ...;
text = text.replace(",", ".");

if(text.length() > 0) {
    try {
        float f = Float.parseFloat(text);
        Log.i(TAG, "Found float " + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%f", f));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You are using a comma when you should be using a period

```
float f1 = Float.parseFloat("1.9698");
```

That should work.

Answer (score 5):

You have added comma instead of '.'

Do like this.

```
float f1 = Float.parseFloat("1.9698");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Float number;
String str=e1.getText().toString();
number = Float.parseFloat(str);
```

Or In one line

```
float float_no = Float.parseFloat("3.1427");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Float total = Float.valueOf(0);
try
{
    total = Float.valueOf(str);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    Number n = null;
    try
    {
        n = df.parse(str);
    } 
    catch(ParseException ex2){ }
    if(n != null)
        total = n.floatValue();
}
```

Comment: Some comments would be good. The questioner is asking why his code does not work. It would be nice to answer that question, too.

Comment: because comma(,) is not converted into float so we use decimalformat

Comment: This would be the right answer. This problem is because there is no character internationalization.And I googled that turkey uses a semicolon for decimals.
Should use ICU https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization
Look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DecimalFormat

Answer (score 1):

This is **Type Conversion**:
type conversion required when we use different type of data in any variables.

```
    String str = "123.22";

    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    float f = Float.parseFloat(str);
    long l = Long.parseLong(str);
    double d= Double.parseDouble(str);

    str = String.valueOf(d);
    str = String.valueOf(i);
    str = String.valueOf(f);
    str = String.valueOf(l);
```

Also some times we need **Type Casting**:
type casting required when we use same data but in different type.
only you cast Big to Small Datatype.

```
    i = (int)f;
    i = (int)d;
    i = (int)l;

    f = (float)d;
    f = (float)l;

    l = (long)d;
```

Answer (score 1):

used this float f1 = Float.parseFloat("1.9698"); or replace ,(comma) with .(dot) that is invalid form of flot number

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin:

```
stringValue.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0F
```

Which will give ***NumberFormatException*** free conversion.

More precise:

```
private fun getFloat(stringValue: String) = stringValue.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0F
```